# Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'Int'

Tags: ios, swift, multiplication

I tried some solutions on this website but could not come up with one.

I keep getting this error with this line of code:

```
func futureValue() {
    let interest = Double(interestInput.text!) ?? 0
    let pv = Double(pvInput.text!) ?? 0
    let years = Double(yearsInput.text!) ?? 0
        
    let result = pv * (1.0 + interest) ^^ years
}
```

The `result` variable is where I receive the error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Interests, pv and years can be 0 and swift will interpret them as Int. But in your result calculation you use 1.0 which is a double. Try using ?? 0.0 instead of ?? 0

Comment: @SwissMark good suggestion, but this did not work. Still throwing the same error..

Comment: What types does the ^^ operator require? I bet that it expects years to be an Int

Comment: @Rob hit the nail on the head. That did it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question, the custom `^^` operator was set for `Int` and not `Double`.

This is **incorrect**:

```
}

precedencegroup PowerPrecedence { higherThan: MultiplicationPrecedence }
infix operator ^^ : PowerPrecedence
func ^^ (radix: Int, power: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(pow(Double(radix), Double(power)))
```

This is the **correct** way, to match the `Double` in the `futureValue()` function:

```
}

precedencegroup PowerPrecedence { higherThan: MultiplicationPrecedence }
infix operator ^^ : PowerPrecedence
func ^^ (radix: Double, power: Double) -> Double {
    return Double(pow(Double(radix), Double(power)))
}
```